# Будет ли FloatBuffer для GL15.glBufferData() быстрее, чем массив float[] на lwjgl 3

Tags: java, opengl, float, lwjgl, buffer

В OpenGL я новичок, начал изучать его на основе lwjgl 3 для java. Заинтересовался этим вопросом, поскольку везде, где использовался GL15.glBufferData() использовали FloatBuffer. К сожалению, всё, что я нашёл - [Клик](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66752349/is-there-any-difference-between-giving-gl15-glbufferdata-a-float-array-or-a-fl). Как ответили в теме, скорость повысится в том случае, если не использовать массив, а напрямую FloatBuffer. Однако это не отвечает на мои вопросы:

1. Получу ли я выигрыш в производительности, если буду загружать вершины с помощью FloatBuffer#put()?
2. Будет ли выигрыш с точки зрения занимаемой оперативной памяти, или наоборот, я "уйду в минус"?

Буду благодарен любой помощи. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: У вас же java, на производительность вы забили...

Comment: @user7860670, У меня java, потому, что я не знаю C++  на том уровне, чтобы сделать больше, чем "HelloWorld". Тем не менее, даже для java решения могут быть плохими и хорошими для производительности. Или я не прав?

Comment: FloatBuffer может быть полезен тем, что при использовании прямой аллокации при интеропе с нативным кодом java рантайм сможет избежать дополнительного копирования памяти во временный буфер. Однако проблема в том, что на фоне общего оверхеда от использования java, какого-то существенного улучшения от этих манипуляций ждать не стоит.

Comment: @user7860670 Возможно вы правы. И всё же, насколько мне известно, java хранит в ByteBuffer только адрес памяти в виде long (за исключением HeapByteBuffer, но он к делу не относится). Я работаю (пытаюсь) с VBO, и их будет довольно много, от 1000. Я не представляю как проводить подобные тесты, опять же, потому, что в OpenGL ещё не имею опыта. И всё же, мне кажется, для большого количества таких объектов, даже крошечная разница может серьёзно повлиять на производительность...

Comment: @user7860670 UPDATE, не увидел, как вы отредактировали комментарий. Вы не знаете, насколько существенна эта разница с временным буфером? Я загружаю модели при старте программы, и мне гораздо удобнее было бы представлять набор вершин в виде массива. Стоит ли попробовать с FloatBuffer?